# How do I pass a tex template to Rmarkdown?

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

I want rmarkdown/knitr to create a pdf output using a custom tex template.

It is possible to override pandoc defaults with:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: '--pdf-engine=xelatex'
---
```

However it is not working when I add a further command:

```
'--pdf-engine=xelatex --template template.tex'
```

The error:

```
Unknown option --template template.tex .
```

- How can I set a custom tex template using rmarkdown?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#custom_templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier solution:

```
mainfont: Minion Pro
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```